# Is there a code snippet can run Azure CLI command in MacOs, Linux and windows?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, .net-core, azure-cli

Here is my code and it's a .NET Core project that the key reason I want perform such action in those platform. My purpose is to run a process to execute this Azure CLI command then get its output.

```
string extendCommand = "az account get-access-token --resource ";

ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c" + extendCommand)
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};

Process proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = procStartInfo
};

proc.Start();
string cliResult = await proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

For now I can execute this command in Window but can't get an idea how it works in MacOs and Linux.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As you known, ".NET Core is a cross-platform version of .NET for building websites, services, and console apps." ffor Windows, Linux, and macOS. You can directly download (from the offical website [Download .NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download)) and install .NET Core SDK in different platform to build the same code of console app like yours without any issue.

So I guess it seems that you were using Visual Studio to create a .NET Core console app on Windows, but don't know how to do it on Linux/MacOC because there is no distribution of Visual Studio on Linux or a different distribution of Visual Studio on MacOS.

Actually, you just need to follow the offical simple tutorial [`.NET Tutorial - Hello World in 10 minutes`](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/intro) to create a console app via commands, which steps are as same as on different platforms. Meanwhile, [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview) with [C#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp) extension is only a cross-platform IDE supports .NET Core with C# language on different platforms, which you can consider to use in your app creation.

For the installation of Azure CLI, except to follow the offical document [`Install the Azure CLI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) to install for differnt platforms by using different native ways, actually Azure CLI also is a normal Python package (its PyPI page https://pypi.org/project/azure-cli/) and includes an executable command `az`, which can be directly installed by command `pip install azure-cli` on Windows/Linux/MacOS if there have been installed Python correctly first.

Even considering for `az` required a Python runtime first, you can directly write a Python script to invoke `az` command via `os.popen('az ....').read()` to read the output.

Even further, you can write a Python script to import `azure-cli` package to directly use the internal APIs, as the code below.

```
from azure.cli.core import get_default_cli

args = ['az', 'account', 'get-access-token', '--resource']
az_cli = get_default_cli()
az_cli.invoke(args)
if az_cli.result.result:
    print(az_cli.result.result)
if az_cli.result.error:
    print(az_cli.result.error)
```

Note: of course, all of the operations above need you to run `az login` first for Azure authentication.